# openssl_get_publickey returns "Resource id #2"

Tags: php, in-app-purchase, verification, public-key, php-openssl

I am doing the In-App Purchase verification server side for android. My PHP Version is 5.6.28, and my OpenSSL version is 1.0.2j .

I am having problems with getting the public key. The code below returns `Resource id #2`:

```
$key = openssl_get_publickey( $publicKey );
```

My public key is created from :

```
"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" . chunk_split($base64EncodedPublicKeyFromGoogle, 64, "\n") .  "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
```

where `base64EncodedPublicKeyFromGoogle` is the public key from google

I tried searching what "Resource id #2" means but cant find any.
Any one knows what this means and how to make `openssl_get_publickey` work?

Comment: Drop the `"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n"` and `"-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n"`. Also see [A note about the openssl_verify() (and some of the other functions) ...](https://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-verify.php#21889)